# Linux: How can I log in as root user on my local machine?

Tags: linux, root, sudo

I would like to be a user with root access, when developing in Visual Studio Code on my local machine.

I read many posts about this but they all depend on using something with `su` or `sudo`. Unfortunately, in my case both return "bash: su(do): command not found".

How can I enable root access for myself?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about your environment? I assume you are running VSCode in some linux distro... which one? what is that your are trying as root?

Comment: I have a Windows computer on which I have VSC installed. I would like to install `nvm` but that fails and I think it's because I don't have root access. `uname -a` returns `MINGW64_NT-10.0 Lenovo-l 2.5.0(0.295/5/3) 2016-03-31 18:47 x86_64 Msys`.

Comment: What you are asking is technically not possible. MSYS is just an environment emulator, but it is not linux! If you want to run something as root ON WINDOWS you have to run the msys environment as an administrator.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I'm a bit out of my depth here. I wonder why installing nvm is not working then... But I guess that's a different question, so I'll open a separate question for that. That you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSYS/MinGW is essentially just a collection of linux utilities compiled as windows executables. It is **not** actually linux, so linux concepts, like the root user, do not apply. Similarly, tools that only work on linux, like nvm, also will not work in MSYS. If you want something that is actually linux, check out the Windows Subsystem for Linux, or WSL.

Comment: Thanks, quick follow-up question, so I can't use `nvm` within this existing environment? If so, is there another way than nvm to downgrade my node version?

Comment: There appears to be [an nvm remake for windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows).

Comment: Sweet, that actually seems to work :)